# Design hierarchial grid in rally using jira open api as data source

Tags: rally

I'm writing a custom HTML app using the 2.1 rally SDK. My tasks are:

1. Write a custom html app to design a hierarchical grid where the data should
   be obtain from a fetch call from Jira Open API.
2. Filter the grid with any word provided

This is my code:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('User', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['FormattedId', 'Name', 'email'],
            associations: [
                {type: 'hasMany', model: 'UserChild',    name: 'UserChild'},
                {type: 'hasMany', model: 'Defects', name: 'Defects'},

            ],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : './Users.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root:'users'
                }
            },
        });

        Ext.define("UserChild", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['FormattedId', 'Name', 'email'],
            belongsTo: 'User'
        });

        Ext.define("Defects", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['FormattedId', 'Name', 'email'],
            belongsTo: 'User'
        });

        var grid=Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            store: Ext.create('Rally.data.Store', {
                model: 'User',

                autoLoad:true,
                enableHierarchy: true
            }),
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                    text:'FormattedId' , dataIndex : 'FormattedId'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    text:'email' , dataIndex : 'email'
                }
            ]
        });
        this.add(grid);
    }
});
```

Users.json file is as below:

```
    {
    "users": [
       {
           "FormattedId": 1,
           "Name": "Ed Spencer",
           "email": "ed@sencha.com",
           "UserChild":{
            "FormattedId": 3,
            "Name": "Ed Spencer",
            "email": "ed@sencha.com"
           },
           "Defects" :{
            "FormattedId": 4,
            "Name": "Ed Spencer",
            "email": "ed@sencha.com"

           }
       },
       {
           "FormattedId": 2,
           "Name": "Abe Elias",
           "email": "abe@sencha.com",
           "UserChild":{
            "FormattedId": 5,
            "Name": "Ed Spencer",
            "email": "ed@sencha.com"
           },
           "Defects" :{
            "FormattedId": 6,
            "Name": "Ed Spencer",
            "email": "ed@sencha.com"

           }
       }
    ]
}
```

I want a hierarchical grid with user data and not rally data store.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to come to a problem when you try to fetch Jira data from within a Rally app. You will most likely be prevented from doing that because of CORS.

The second big problem you will have is that all the Rally SDK objects are based on their being a 'record' object with all the right variables and procedures. The hierarchy is based on children collections of various types, not associations. The hierarchical grids make that even harder because they use a hand-crafted bit of black magic to get it all to work together and is very resistant to modifications.

Good luck.

Comment: HI Can you elaborate more and give me a good example for children collection of various types

Comment: Luckily, it's all in the manuals: 
https://docs.ca.com/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/